# Page carousel control buttons uneventy placed

Tags: html, css, carousel

This is going to sound really trivial but there is a space between the left two carousel control buttons and the two right ones, making them unevenly spaced.

I've tried the CSS `margin` attribute on the left and right sides of the `li` but the space sill remains. Has anyone else had this trouble?

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators main-carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-main" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
                </ol>
<style>
.main-carousel-indicators{
padding: 2px;
}
.main-carousel-indicators li{
height: 14px;
width: 14px;
}
.main-carousel-indicators li.active{
height: 14px;
width: 14px;
}
.carousel-indicators li{
background-color:white;
border-color:transparent !important;
transition: all 0.25s ease;

}
.carousel-indicators .active{
background-color:#0D0155;
border-color:transparent !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please post your code or a shortened version of it so that we can help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you have space betwen buttons because li are display: inline;

```
.main-carousel-indicators li{
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```